# LINQ to SQL DataContext To XML With XSD Schema

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, linq, linq-to-xml

I have some data in my Linq.DataContext.

I had succes in converting it to an XSD - Schema, using the following code:

```
Dim changeset As System.Data.Linq.ChangeSet = c.GetChangeSet()
Dim objDic As New Dictionary(Of System.Type, List(Of Object))

If Not changeset Is Nothing AndAlso Not changeset.Inserts Is Nothing AndAlso Not changeset.Inserts.Count = 0 Then

For Each i As Object In changeset.Inserts

    Dim t As System.Type = i.GetType()

    If objDic.ContainsKey(t) Then
        objDic(t).Add(i)
    Else
        Dim l As New List(Of Object)
        l.Add(i)
        objDic(t) = l
    End If

Next

'XML schema 

For Each t As System.Type In objDic.Keys
    Dim s As New System.IO.FileStream(String.Format("{0}{1}", LinqBulkInsert.My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, "\xmlschema.xsd"), System.IO.FileMode.Create)

    Using xmlw As New System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(s, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)

        xmlw.WriteStartDocument()
        xmlw.WriteStartElement("xsd:schema")
        xmlw.WriteAttributeString("xmlns:xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")
        xmlw.WriteAttributeString("xmlns:sql", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mapping-schema")
        xmlw.WriteStartElement("xsd:element")
        xmlw.WriteAttributeString("name", t.Name)
        xmlw.WriteAttributeString("sql:relation", c.Mapping.GetTable(t).TableName)
        xmlw.WriteStartElement("xsd:complexType")
        xmlw.WriteStartElement("xsd:sequence")

        Dim pinfos As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo() = t.GetProperties

        For Each pi As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo In pinfos
            If Not pi.PropertyType.Equals(GetType(System.Guid)) Then
                xmlw.WriteStartElement("xsd:element")
                xmlw.WriteAttributeString("name", pi.Name)
                xmlw.WriteAttributeString("type", "xsd:" & XsdTypeConverter.getInstance.GetSimpleType(pi.PropertyType))
                xmlw.WriteEndElement()
            End If
        Next
        xmlw.WriteEndDocument()
        xmlw.Flush()

    End Using

    s.Close()
    'Schema wordt succesvol weggeschreven in xmlschema.xsd

Next
```

Now my question is, how can i extract the data to a complete readabke XML file (with all data in it).

Comment: Do not use `new XmlTextWriter()`. It's been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use DataContract and DataMember attributes in your context. Read these articles:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546185.aspx 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546184.aspx